# addInstance function in google-api-client appears to have errors in it

Tags: gcloud, google-api-client

In the following code as seen as on this site

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance

```
def addInstance(http, listOfHeaders):
  url = "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/zones/[ZONE]/instances"

  body = {
    "name": "[INSTANCE_NAME]",
    "machineType": "machineTypes/[MACHINE_TYPE]",
    "networkInterfaces": [{
      "accessConfigs": [{
        "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
        "name": "External NAT"
       }],
      "network": "global/networks/default"
    }],
    "disks": [{
       "autoDelete": "true",
       "boot": "true",
       "type": "PERSISTENT",
       "initializeParams": {
         "sourceImage": "projects/[IMAGE_PROJECT]/global/images/family/[IMAGE]",
         "labels": {
           "key": "[LABEL_KEY]",
           "value": "[LABEL_VALUE]",
         }
       }
     },
     {
       "initializeParams": {
          "diskSizeGb": "[SIZE_GB]",
          "sourceImage":"[IMAGE]"
       },
       {
       "initializeParams": {
          "diskSizeGb": "[SIZE_GB]"
       }
     }]

  bodyContentURLEncoded = urllib.urlencode(bodyContent)
  resp, content = http.request(uri=url, method="POST", body=dumps(bodyContent), headers=listOfHeaders)

  print resp
  print content
```

First, the code is written in Python 2.7 syntax.  Second, the urllib module throws the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlencode'
```

Third, even if it did not throw that error `bodyContent` would thrown an `unresolvedReference error` since has not been referred to.  Fourth, there is no explanation as to what `http` refers to or what type it is, same with `listofheaders`.  Finally, the `dumps` method, I'm not sure they have that in Python3

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there are some mistakes in the code, thanks for noticing. I have just opened a request for it's correction, although there's no ETA as of today.

Meanwhile there are other options to create GCE instances. You may use the Cloud console UI, the gcloud command line utility, the official client libraries. Documentation for all of them can be found in the same page you [linked](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance). Alternatively you could follow this [page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses) that shows how to create instances through curl linux command in a similar fashion as in the question's example.

With that being said, StackOverflow it's a question&answer community and it's not the best place to report this kind of discoveries, next time kindly consider to request changes using the "Send Feedback" link that appears at the bottom of each page in Google's Documentation.